# echo 1 > /sys/bus/pci/slots/$4/power bash: /sys/bus/pci/slots//power: Permission denied

Tags: power-management, pci

On typing `echo 1 > /sys/bus/pci/slots/$4/power`, I get this error:

```
bash: /sys/bus/pci/slots//power: Permission denied
```

Here is the output of `lscpi -vv`on my system:

```
02:00.0 Multimedia controller: Digital Devices GmbH Octopus DVB Adapter
        Subsystem: Digital Devices GmbH Cine S2 V6.5 DVB adapter
        Physical Slot: 4
        Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 46
        Memory at c7400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
        Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [70] MSI: Enable+ Count=2/2 Maskable- 64bit+
        Capabilities: [90] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
        Capabilities: [100] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0000 Rev=0 Len=00c <?>
        Kernel driver in use: ddbridge

06:00.0 Multimedia controller: Digital Devices GmbH Max
        Subsystem: Digital Devices GmbH Max S8 4/8
        Physical Slot: 3
        Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 49
        Memory at c7300000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
        Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [70] MSI: Enable+ Count=2/2 Maskable- 64bit+
        Capabilities: [90] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
        Capabilities: [100] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0000 Rev=0 Len=00c <?>
        Kernel driver in use: ddbridge
```

Comment: What is $4 supposed to be? Bash is seeing it as empty, hence the // in the path. Once you figure out what should be in place of $4 (which I believe means the fourth argument of a script), you should have it.

Answer (score 4):

`echo` won't work like that.

You would need use `sudo tee` instead like so to allow permission:

```
echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/bus/pci/slots/4/power
```

Also, I think you probably meant to specify slot 4 which would be 4 instead of $4.